# What did I get wrong in this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals, completing-the-square

$$\int \frac{(x+1)dx}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$$

completing the square:

$$1-(x^2-2x+1)$$
$$1-(x+1)^2$$
$$a^2-U^2$$

we have:
$$U = (x+1) $$
$$a = 1$$

we have:

$$\int \frac{UdU}{\sqrt{a^2-U^2}}$$

let: $ U= a\sin\theta$ and $dU = a\cos\theta d\theta$
hence:

$$\int \frac{a\sin\theta a\cos\theta}{a\cos\theta}$$
$$ = -a\cos\theta$$
$$ = -\sqrt{2x-x^2}$$

Which is wrong, what did I miss?

Comment: $x^2-2x+1$ is $(x-1)^2$.

Comment: should I replace the x+1 in the numerator as U+1?

Comment: If you are replacing $x+1$ as $U+1$, do you really intend to let $U=x$?

Comment: sorry x = U+ 1.

Comment: If $x=U+1$, then $x+1=U+2$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $1-(x-1)^2$ rather than $1-(x+1)^2$

Comment: should I replace the x+1 in the numerator as U+1?

Comment: I would write $U=x-1$. So $x+1$ would be $U+2$